# Structure array erases data

Tags: c

I try to fill a structure array with a loop that call a function to do it.
every time i loop more than once the the first entry erases the the first entry from the last call, i suspect that its something with the CALLOC() function but not sure need help.
Here is the function:

```
HOUSE setHouse(int count, HOUSE *house) {
    int max = 20;
    printf("Enter Family(%d) name (%d charecter max):\n", count + 1, max);
    char *familyName = calloc(max, sizeof(char));
    if(familyName != NULL) {
        scanf("%s", familyName);
        house -> name = familyName;
        free(familyName);
    } else {
        printf("Allocation faild\n");
        house -> name = NULL;
    }
    printf("Enter house number:\n");
    scanf("%d", &house -> adress);  
    printf("Enter number of rooms:\n");
    scanf("%d", &house -> rooms);    
    printf("Enter size of house (in sqMt sss.ss format):\n");
    scanf("%f", &house -> sqMeters);
    return *house;
}
```

This is the call to the function:

```
int nHouses = 0;
    printf("Number of houses in your street: ?\n");
    scanf("%d", &nHouses);
    HOUSE myHouse[nHouses];
    for (int i = 0; i < nHouses; i++) {
        setHouse(i, &myHouse[i]);
    }
```

Here is example of the result with two iterations:
in the first iteration give the family name of 'a', and the second the family name 'b'.

```
Family  Number  Rooms   Size
a       1       1       1.00
        1       1       1.00
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You're freeing `familyName` as soon as you assign it to `house->name`. You're creating a dangling pointer. Don't free it until you're done using it.

Comment: But when after assign it to `house->name` what `familyName` contains is not relevant anymore?

Comment: It's a pointer, so yes, it's relevant. What you're doing is equivalent to `house->name = familyName; free(house->name);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the bug:

```
if(familyName != NULL) {
    scanf("%s", familyName);
    house -> name = familyName;
    free(familyName);
} else {
    printf("Allocation faild\n");
    house -> name = NULL;
}
```

You call `free(familyName)` directly after assigning the pointer to `house->name` so you have a pointer to an already freed piece of memory afterwards and accessing that invokes Undefined Behaviour

Instead, you could create a loop like

```
for( i=0; i<nHouses; i++ ) {
    free( house[i].name );
}
```

That you call when you don't need the whole array any more

Comment: where the call to free(familyName) should be made?

Comment: I put it in the code just after i print the whole array and it dose print all the data but the program ends with an error: ProgramingInC(7247,0x1000d1dc0) malloc: *** error for object 0x100507230: pointer being freed was not allocated.

Comment: hard to say anything about that without seeing the whole code, but if you really assign either NULL or the result of an individual `calloc()` to **each** `house[i].name`  that error wouldn't occur

Comment: This did work: 'for(int i = 0; i < nHouses; i++ ) {
        myHouse[i].name = NULL;
    } ' free() didn't. thank you :)

Comment: But tha doesn't free the memory!

Comment: it didn't free it and i tried moving the loop to other places in the "free() loop" but it keep getting the same error, maybe i don't understand something basic about it. but i was thinking that every time i call the function calloc() allocates different memory address for every myHouse.name[i].

Comment: yes, every `calloc()` will return a different address if you don't call `free()` in between. Otherwise, freed memory might be reused (but not neccessarily)

Comment: maybe you can call another question with the updated code including thre 'free() loop' referring to this one.